# trying to change cursor in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, png

I want a function in javascript that changes my cursor to a png image when the button is clicked.  This is the code I've been playing with in the html and javascript, but obviously it doesn't work, can someone help me?

```
<form>
    <input type="button"
           onclick="changeCursor()"
           value="click here"
    />
</form>
```

...

```
function changeCursor() {
    cursor.style = "myImage.png"
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `cursor`. If you want to change the cursor, you  need to use CSS, not JavaScript.

Comment: but how do i change the css in my javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url

Answer (score 2):

When the button is clicked add the `cursor` property.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.style.cursor = 'url(http://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/fff), auto';
})
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: coral;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<input id="btn" type="button" value="click here" />
```

Comment: "when the button is clicked", not on hover... Upvoted for the rest.

Comment: i want the button to make the cursor permanently my image, not just when it hovers over it, can you tell me how I could do that?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py You're only applying the cursor to `div`, I think he wants it applied to everything. Perhaps `document.body.style.cursor = url('');` would be better?

Comment: this is really confusing, when I run the code snippet here it works fine, but as soon as I copy pasted the code into my text editor it did nothing when i clicked the button and threw no error...

Comment: wait, it's not the code that's wrong, for some reason my png file isn't working.  can only certain images become cursors?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to, you can use JQuery too:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="click here" />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
body.newcursor
{
    cursor: url(http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lqs4qoKE1V1qfoi4t.png), auto;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').click(function(){
        $('body').addClass('newcursor');
    });        
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/jx6j6uho/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can affect the cursor by setting CSS to `cursor: url(myImage.png), auto`. You could assign this to `document.body.style`, but you would overwrite anything that is there if you are not careful. Better way is to assign it to a CSS class, and append the class to `<body>` element.